# Meteor 1.3: how to route to a new template on 'tester' Todos app?

Tags: meteor

I'm going through the Todos app for learning purposes, and trying to add my own route. This is not working, and I am unable (at this point) to figure out why. Is there something I'm missing?

In /imports/startup/client/routes.js I added the route:

```
FlowRouter.route('/users', {
  name: 'Users.show',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('App_body', { main: 'Users_show_page'});
  },
});
```

I then added a users-show-page.html file:

```
<template name="Users_show_page">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</template>
```

All I see is a blank screen where the template should be, with no kind of errors as to why my template is not showing up :(

=== EDIT ===

You need to import the templates into the router.js file. It would be nice if there was an error message saying your template couldn't be found. This is the case for top level templates, but apparently not for components called by `{{> Template.dynamic template=main}}`

Comment: Totally agree - question: are you importing the HTML and JS for each template as a separate import statement in your routes.js? That's what I'm doing but I feel like there could be a better way - thoughts?

Comment: On the routes.js file I'm importing the <templateName>.js. Then on <templateName>.js I'm importing <templateName>.html. I think this is to decrease the total amount of imports that are done (i.e if a route doesn't require a template, then only the .js will have been loaded and not the HTML - this is how the todos app does it).